# NodeJS enviar arquivos server to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, arquivo, upload, request

Boa tarde amigos, 
Estou tentando enviar um arquivo de uma aplicação minha (em node) para um servidor Web feito em PHP. Porém esta retornando a mensagem dizendo que o parametro do arquivo (arqCsv) não foi encontrado. 
No exemplo orientado pela documentação do mesmo, eles utilizam o cURL no PHP:

```
$ipServidor      = '192.168.0.1' 
$arquivo         = '/tmp/arquivo.csv'; 
$campos          = 'idext:cpf:nome'; 
$idIntegracao    = 0;
$pularBLS        = 0; 
$incremental     = 0; 
$ativaAoImportar = 0; 

$post = array(
    'arqCsv'       => '@'.$arquivo, // No cURL, o '@' significa Envio de Arquivo.
    'campos'       => $campos,
    'idintegracao' => $idIntegracao,
    'pularBLS'     => $pularBLS,
    'incremental'  => $incremental,
    'ativar'       => $ativaAoImportar
    );

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,  "http://$ipServidor/software/servicos/importar.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Sendo que ja fiz diversos testes em meu sistema para enviar o arquivo, tanto usando o modulo Request, Modulo [Form-Data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) e o modulo [Restler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/restler).

Segue exemplo de código utilizando o Módulo Restler.

```js
SendFile(fileName, campos, idintegracao) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
   console.log(`Localizando arquivo ${fileName}`)
   //Funciona perfeitamente, mas nao ve o arquivo.

   fs.stat(fileName, function(err, stats) {
    restler.post("http://servico.com/aplicacao/servicos/importar.php", {
     multipart: true,
     data: {
      "idintegracao": idintegracao,
      "campos": campos.toString().split(',').join(':'),
      "arqCsv": restler.file(fileName, null, stats.size, null, "text/csv")
     }
    }).on("complete", function(data) {
     console.log(data);
     res(data)
    });
   });
   return ;
   });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o módulo [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), mais especificamente o envio de [`Forms`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#forms) da seguinte forma:

```
const request = require('request');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const enviar = (campos, idintegracao) => {
  return new Promise((resolver, rejeitar) => {
    const formData = {
      idintegracao,
      ...campos,
      arqCsv: fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, '/tmp/arquivo.csv')),
    };

    request.post({ url: 'http://servico.com/aplicacao/servicos/importar.php', formData }, function callback (erro, resposta, body) {
      if (erro) return rejeitar('Envio falhou:', erro);
      resolver('Enviado com sucesso! O servidor respondeu:', body);
    });
  });
};

module.exports = {
  enviar,
};
```